# No data retrieved from influxdb using node.js

Tags: node.js, backend, influxdb

I am trying to create a backend server using node.js and retriewing data from influxdb

But whenever I run the localhost i am getting output as [] only and not the stock data

Please tell me what my error is .Chatgpt is saying its Completely Fine but still output is not coming

```
 app.get('/stocks/:symbol', async (req, res) => {
  const symbol = req.params.symbol;

  // Define the Flux query
  const fluxQuery = `
    from(bucket: "${bucket}")
      |> range(start: -2y)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "stocks")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "close" or r["_field"] == "high" or r["_field"] == "low" or r["_field"] == "open")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["symbol"] == "${symbol}")
  `;

  try {
    // Execute the Flux query
    const queryApi = influxDB.getQueryApi(org);
    const result = await queryApi.queryRaw(fluxQuery);

    // Extract the data from the result
    const data = result?.table?.rows || [];

    // Extract column names from the result
    const columns = result?.table?.columns || [];

    // Map the rows to objects using column names as keys
    const formattedData = data.map(row => {
      const obj = {};
      columns.forEach((column, index) => {
        obj[column] = row[index];
      });
      return obj;
    });

    // Send the data as the server response
    res.json(formattedData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving data from InfluxDB:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

Comment: I would begin with some debugging, like `console.log(result?.table?.rows)` around the assignment to `columns`